# servicenow report list all ticket on which my group worked

Tags: servicenow

How to generate report in servicenow to display list of all ticket *(regardless of ticket type and current status & current assigned group)* **WHICH are assigned to my group/team member** OR in other words, listing of all ticket on which my team member worked regardless of current assigned to or state.

**I want to see all incidents opened last month that were assigned to my groups at some time**

Answer (score 0):

You can find whether an incident was assigned to a user from record history. You can write a script to filter the history on "assigned to" and then check if the user belongs to your team.

Answer (score 0):

Replace XXXXX by your domain name to get the report

https://XXXXX.service-now.com/task_list.do?sysparm_query=assignment_group%3Djavascript%3AgetMyGroups()%5Eactive%3Dtrue%5Eassignment_group.typeLIKE7aab6a7895121000f9acb7a2692bd189%5EGROUPBYassigned_to&sysparm_first_row=1&sysparm_view=